# Combine text in cells vertically

Tags: excel, vba

Someone created a text document in Excel like it was on a typewriter. They wrote to the end of the screen then hit enter.

I'd like to put each paragraph into it's own cell then copy and paste to Word.

I tried recording a macro, but it get stuck between paragraphs (author skipped a line between paragraphs).  My research shows concatenating cells one at a time, which won't help me with about 1000 lines of text.

The VBA would be something like:

```
' If cell below isn't empty
' then
' activecell=activecell&activecell(0,1)
' delete activecell(0,1)
' else activecell(0,2).select
'endif
'loop 1000 times
```

If the current document says:

```
A boy walked down
the street.

Next he tried
to run.

Finally this task
was over.
```

After it would look like:

```
A boy walked down the street.

Next he tried to run.

Finally this task was over.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming my assumptions are correct, try the following:

1. Copy everything to Word.
2. Do a Find/Replace for two carriage returns (`^p^p`) and replace them with a placeholder string (ex.: `%%%%%`, anything will do as long as it is not in your document)
3. Do a Find/Replace for single carriage returns (`^p`) and replace them with a single space ()
4. Do a Find/Replace for your placeholder string (`%%%%%` in my example above) and replace it with two carriage returns (`^p^p`)
5. You may need to do a Find/Replace on double-spaces and replace them with single spaces.

After proofing and perhaps some tweaking, you should be done.

Comment: Thanks!  That was driving me bonkers.  I appreciate it!  Saved me a few hours of doing it manually!

Comment: I once had to do this on a regular basis, so I turned into a Macro that I kept in my local template!

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
Sub compileDoc()
    Dim textArr(), r As Long, n As Long, curPar As String

    textArr = Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    n = LBound(textArr)
    For r = LBound(textArr) To UBound(textArr)
        If Len(textArr(r, 1)) Then
            curPar = curPar & " " & textArr(r, 1)
            textArr(r, 1) = ""
        Else
            textArr(n, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Trim(curPar)
            n = n + 1
            curPar = ""
        End If
    Next r
    textArr(n, 1) = curPar
    Sheet1.Range("B2:B" & n + 1) = textArr
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Additional option, text can be copied from the immediate window after running the macro. You can access this through View or Ctrl+ G in the VBA developer window.

```
Sub Concatenate_Text()
Dim i As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim paragraph As String

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lastrow
    If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, "A")) = False Then
    paragraph = paragraph & " " & ws.Cells(i, "A").Value & " " & ws.Cells(i + 1, "A").Value
    i = i + 1
    Else: paragraph = paragraph & vbCrLf
    End If

Next i

Debug.Print paragraph

End Sub
```